# XML - Only one top level is allowed error - Can't find what's wrong with the root element

Tags: xml

I'm fairly new to XML coding and is currently reading about it. I got a setup file from a flash game that I am trying to play around to learn how it works, change questions, change correct answers etc.

Upon opening it using XMLVP, i get the top level error. I read that there should only be one root element which should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` , but I'm not familiar at this early stage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Title>Who wants to be a Millionaire?!</Title>
<Random>yes</Random>
<AllQuestions>

<Q>
<question>Pertains to a Payee that is approved by the client for processing?</question>
<answer>3</answer>
<choice_1>Manual Payee</choice_1>
<choice_2>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>Auto Payee Verification</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>

<Q>
<question>It’s the Manual Verification of payee names by an individual</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Payee List</choice_1>
<choice_2>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Endorsement</choice_3>
<choice_4>Manual Payee Verification</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What do you call the list of payee names for MPV?</question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_1>
<choice_2>Payee List</choice_2>
<choice_3>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>Default Payee(s)</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What are the 4 Payee Groups?</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Acceptable Payee(s)</choice_1>
<choice_2>Abbreviations & Default Payee(s)</choice_2>
<choice_3>Unacceptable Payee(s)</choice_3>
<choice_4>All of the Above</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What does an Asterisk (*) symbol next to a payee name mean?</question>
<answer>3</answer>
<choice_1>Plus Everything</choice_1>
<choice_2>Plus Nothing</choice_2>
<choice_3>Plus Anything</choice_3>
<choice_4>Plus Acceptable Name</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When validating payees, is it acceptable to combined words from a list of payees?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>This is a term used to identify the recipient of the fund. </question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Default Payee</choice_1>
<choice_2>Unacceptable Payee</choice_2>
<choice_3>Acceptable Payee</choice_3>
<choice_4>Payee</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When reviewing a payee name with a hyphen (-), we must make sure both of the payees on the check are acceptable</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: When reviewing a payee name with a slash (/), we must we make sure both of the payees on the check are acceptable.</question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>What does “FBO” stand for? </question>
<answer>2</answer>
<choice_1>Failed Benefit Of</choice_1>
<choice_2>For the Benefit Of</choice_2>
<choice_3>Further Benefits of</choice_3>
<choice_4>Far Benefits of</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>“BankOne” considered as a Default Payee?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Both</choice_3>
<choice_4>Maybe</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>Do we process a check payable to “Cash”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: A check stamped “Per Env” can be processed under “All Payees”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>True or False: A check stamped “Per Mat” can be processed under “All Payees”?</question>
<answer>1</answer>
<choice_1>True</choice_1>
<choice_2>False</choice_2>
<choice_3>Maybe</choice_3>
<choice_4>Both</choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


<Q>
<question>An endorsement is a signature or stamp on the back of a check to?</question>
<answer>4</answer>
<choice_1>Make it payable</choice_1>
<choice_2>Approve Payment</choice_2>
<choice_3>Trnsfr Ownrshp frm 1 prty to anthr</choice_3>
<choice_4></choice_4>
</Q>
<Q>


</AllQuestions>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is the XML declaration, not the root element.  Your example is a well-formed *fragment* of XML (specifically it is a "[well-formed external parsed entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wf-entities)") but it is not a well-formed XML *document* as it has three separate root-level elements `Title`, `Random` and `AllQuestions`.

A well-formed XML document must have exactly one element at the root level, so you would need to wrap these three elements in a *single* root-level element in order to make it a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Can you please point me to the general direction on what I should read or research to have it fixed?

Comment: @ParadoxicalCat it depends what you mean by "fixed" - your question suggests that you got this file from somewhere else and are trying to edit it, so it's a format you don't control.  While it's not an XML document this file is presumably already in the right form for that particular piece of software, and if you changed it to make it well-formed on its own then it wouldn't work as a setup file for the game any more.